# Each finite extension of a field, has a finite number of intermediate extensions.

Tags: galois-theory

Prove that every finite extension $K$ of a field $F$, has a finite number of intermediate extensions.

**EDIT:** All fields here are of characteristic $0$, otherwise we would need to require the extension to be separable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each finite extension $K$ can be injected into a normal extension $K'$. Then $|G(K',F)|=[K':F]=n<\infty$. However, $G(K,F)<G(K',F)$. Therefore $|G(K,F)|=[K:F]\leq n<\infty$. Now $|G(K,F)|$ can only have a finite number of subgroups, then by the Fundamental theorem of Galois theory, there can only be a finite number of intermediate fields. q.e.d.

**N.B.** What is more $$|G(K,F)|=|G(K',K)|=[K':K]$$
and
$$|G(K',K):G(K,F)|=\frac{|G(K',K)|}{|G(K,F)|}=\frac{[K',F]}{[K',K]}=[K:F]$$

Comment: Why is the extension separable?

Comment: @BenjaLim, I forgot to say that this only goes for fields of characteristic $0$.